# Struggling with array and foreach loop

Tags: array, php

I have a function that outputs an array with 2 objects(?):
`Array ( [de] => 166 [it] => 167 )`
Where [xx] is de language code and the number is the pageID.

I'm having a meltdown in my brain as I cannot figure out anymore how to use the pageID's in a foreach loop.

EDIT: See [here](https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_post_duplicates/) as the reference of what I'm doing.
The filter outputs the above and I only need to two numbers (which are page-ids), but I cannot figure out how to get them out.

Can someone lend me a helping hand to show me how to do this again. I know it should be something relatively simple, but I'm drawing blanks :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `foreach ($array as $lan => $pageID){}` ?

Comment: I probably should have made it more clear, because the pageID is not mentioned as such, please have a look here: https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_post_duplicates/

Comment: @Sisir I edited my question to hopefully make it more clear. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an array with just the numbers by using

```
array_values($your_array);
```

It will return an array with just the numbers. Is this what you need, or a string with a comma separated list of IDs?

If that's the case, use this:

```
implode(",",array_values($your_array));
```

Hope this helps.